# Return cscript output to batch

Tags: batch-file, jscript, wsh

My batch script is performing an HTTP request by using CScript with Javascript syntax like in my example.

Using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26628654/875020) (also [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17881057/875020)) and some [help on escaping](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php) i tried the following:

```
@if (@This==@IsBatch) @then
@echo off
rem **** batch zone *********************************************************
    setlocal enableextensions EnableDelayedExpansion

    set OWNPATH="%~dpnx0"

    if not "%~11"=="" (
        FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%r in (`cscript //E:JScript %OWNPATH%`) DO SET RESULT=%%r
        ECHO %RESULT%
    )

    exit /b

@end
// **** JScript zone *****************************************************
// Instantiate the needed component to make url queries
var http = WScript.CreateObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0');

// perform request
var requestURL = "http://myserver/api";

// Make the request 
http.open("GET", requestUrl, false);
http.send();

WScript.Echo(http.ResponseText);

// All done. Exit
WScript.Quit(0);
```

Unfortunately i get a message that "ECHO is off." and not the string in *%RESULT%*.

The script is run on a Windows 2008 R2 server.

Comment: you need [delayed expansion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082)

Comment: Thanks, got it! `echo !RESULT!` works!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variables in batch not behaving as expected](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30282784/692942)

Comment: Also consider the `/nologo` switch for `cscript`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Stephan it works when using

```
echo !RESULT!
```

due to the [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/7926064)